# Is the onCreate run on the main thread?

Tags: android, intentservice, oncreate, android-intentservice

I understand that IntentServices allow running tasks on worker threads, however is the worker thread only spawn on call back to `onHandleIntent`?

Is the `onCreate()` called on the main thread and any object creation that takes place in the `onCreate` also takes place on the main thread?

Comment: You could find this out very easily by logging `Thread.currentThread.getName()` inside of your `oncreate()`.

Comment: short answer: yes

Answer (score 4):

Yes, onCreate() runs on the main thread.
If you print out the thread name in onCreate(), you get the following:

```
Thread[main,5,main]
```

However, you can spawn off background thread inside onCreate() if you don't want to block the main thread.